# Create userform listbox right click menu

Tags: excel, vba

I created a userform in Excel. I populated it with data using a Listbox that reads from a range in Excel.

I'm trying to add the ability to right click on a row in the Listbox and then perform an action on that line of data from there. Is this possible?

I was planning on:

1. Creating a custom popup menu
2. Working on setting up some sort of event in the userform on right click
3. Everything else.

I'm stuck on step 1 above. I started by trying to create a custom right-click menu by using the code from Microsoft's website on "showpopup".

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.commandbar.showpopup

```vb
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Set myBar = CommandBars _
    .Add(Name:="Custom", Position:=msoBarPopup, Temporary:=False)
With myBar
    .Controls.Add Type:=msoControlButton, ID:=3
    .Controls.Add Type:=msoControlComboBox
End With
myBar.ShowPopup

End Sub
```

I created a new userform and pasted the code verbatim from MS's website.

I get this error:

> Run-time error: '5': Invalid procedure call or argument

This is the line that's causing the error:

```
Set myBar = CommandBars _
    .Add(Name:="Custom", Position:=msoBarPopup, Temporary:=False)
```

Comment: This link may help:  [MrExcel - Add A Right-click Menu To A User Form](https://www.mrexcel.com/excel-tips/add-a-right-click-menu-to-a-user-form/)

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook thank you for that link. Reading through it now, I'll need to re-read it a few times to get a grasp on what's going on here. But thank you, looks like it covers everything from start to finish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error is that the CommandBar already exists ... before the line that is erroring, add:

```
On Error Resume Next
CommandBars.Item("Custom").Delete
On Error GoTo 0
```

... you should also really run the same lines to delete the CommandBar when your UserForm is no longer in use, maybe in the Terminate event

... also your code, as it stands, shows the CommandBar immediately, you likely want to move the `myBar.ShowPopup` line elsewhere (eg to the appropriate event handler for the ListBox)

Comment: Oh wow that worked, thank you very much. When you say commandbar already existing, are you referring to the existing right click menus etc.? 

Is it possible to create a new one unique to just this form then?

Comment: The CommandBar is added to the application's (ie Excel's in this case) collection of CommandBar objects. That collection can only have one CommandBar for each name (CommandBar names must be unique). The first time your code runs, it will work fine as it is adding the first CommandBar called "Custom". However, the second and every subsequent time it is erroring as a CommandBar called "Custom" already exists. Best practice is always to try and delete a CommandBar before you add it. That's the bit that my suggested code does.

Comment: And to answer your question, the CommandBar isn't really unique to the UserForm, but if you create it when the UserForm is being initialised and then delete it when the UserForm is being terminated then no other code has a chance to use it ... you are creating a 'bespoke' CommandBar just for the UserForm